# asp.net mvc logging framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logging

We need a logging framework that would allow us to do the following

1. Log all unhandled exceptions
2. Log the pages that a user visits and be able to reproduce their
   history (so we can try and optimise the site better for user usage
   patterns)
3. Log any custom messages that we might want to output in various
   places in the code, ie. warning/information
4. Log asp.net membership sucess/failure
5. Log any other system related events

I've seen that ELMAH will do the #1, the asp.net health monitoring seems like it will handle #4 and #5 and possibly #2 (not 100% sure on that one though), and something like either NLog or Log4Net will take care of #3.

[I did find a tutorial](http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/logging-in-mvc-part-5-the-model-and-data-layer/) on implementing all of these but I'm wondering if its neccessary to have all of those libraries just for this type of logging, seems a bit much and then you have the overhead of trying to combine them into a standard type of view if thats how you are going to display them.

Is there a simpler way than this ?

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I like having different system logging different types of data.  Each of these are, as I see it, different domains of logging roles.  An analyst shouldn't care about #1 exceptions, those are for developers, and developers should care about say #2 (Google Analytics or Adobe SiteCatalyst).  I feel that allowing the different systems to log as needed and distribute the logging information differently is appropriate although as you stated it is a bit much.

This question should probably have been asked on Programmers.StackExchange.Com.

Comment: Yeah I'm torn between simplicity and functionality